# Rails Prawn randomly generates corrupt PDF files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, rails-activestorage, prawn

I'm having an issue with the Rails prawn gem. It happens very rarely and seems to be completely random. When it does happen, the PDF that is generated has all garbled text. There's no error message or anything, just what looks like a PDF with code in it instead of the formatted text it's supposed to have.

If I try regenerating the PDF, the problem keeps happening until I change the content of the PDF file (by changing the value in a form field, like changing a Yes/No radio button, or changing the text input in a text field). Then when I generate the file again, the issue is gone and the PDF is formatted properly. And if I then change the form fields back to where they were previously (when I was getting the error), I don't get the error anymore and it works fine.

I'm saving the file to Active Storage and encrypting it with the Lockbox gem and then displaying a preview of the file in an iframe.

Here's my code:

## profiles_controller.rb

```
def generate_preview
        @profile = current_user.profile
        @profile.generate_file(@profile)
        redirect_to profile_preview_path
end

def show_file
        @profile = current_user.profile
        @file = @profile.file
        send_data @file.download, filename: "Profile-#{@profile.user.name}.pdf", type: @file.content_type, :disposition => :inline
    end
```

## profile.rb

```
has_one_attached :file
encrypts_attached :file

def generate_file(profile)
    @profile = profile
    @pdf_file = ProfilePdf.new(@profile)
    io = StringIO.new @pdf_file.render

    file.attach(io: io, content_type: "application/pdf", filename: 'Profile.pdf')
    file.analyze
end
```

## preview.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md iframe-preview-column">
            <iframe src=<%= profiles_show_file_path + "#toolbar=0" %> class="iframe-preview" style="border: none;"> </iframe>
        </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hey Tony, is @file.content_type (in show_file) different when it's corrupted?

Comment: Hey @AndrewKane, I'm not sure yet - I've been trying to reproduce the issue tonight to check and of course it's not happening right now. Can you tell me more about what you're thinking the issue might be?

Comment: The Lockbox tests around `content_type` have been flaky. I just pushed a fix to master to make content type reliable. You should be able to reproduce your issue by setting `content_type: "text/x-matlab"` in the `show_file` method.

Comment: I just pushed a new release, and here are instructions for fixing existing files: https://github.com/ankane/lockbox#036

Comment: You are correct, setting content_type: "text/x-matlab" in show_file did allow me to reproduce the issue. Thanks for pushing that fix!